# Initializing global variable with function call in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, scope, initialization, global-variables

Today I accidently declared a variable in the global scope and initialized it with the return value of a function call. The code compiled with visual studio 2015 without a problem, and I was surprised that it did. I went to an online C compiler, because I don't have one, and tried to compile but it failed with the error message:

> error: initializer element is not constant.

Well, I am surprised to have seen this because naturally, C++ does not allow VLA unlike C11. I mean, C++ tend to be more strict than C.

Why is this allowed in C++ but not in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *G_ptr = (char *)malloc(1000);

int main(void)
{
    strcpy(G_ptr, "Hello, World");
    puts(G_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because C++ allows it, and C does not.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting beyond "that's just the way it is". For what it's worth: if you do this, be wary of dependencies between variables. You have no control over their initialisation order, and it's easy to make an absolutely mess. If you get into that situation it will be hard to debug since it will crash before even reaching main().

Comment: As a guess, I'd say it's allowed in C++ and not in C because in C++ constructors for global objects need to be run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although C++ tends to be more strict than C as far as their shared features go (no implicit declarations, implied const-ness of string literals, and so on), initialization of variables in file scope with non-const expressions was an entirely new feature. It has been in the language since the first standard came out.

The feature is somewhat controversial, because the order of initialization is unspecified for variables in different translation units. I suspect that this may contribute to the reluctance of the standards committee to add a similar feature to one of the newer C standards.

Comment: "static scope" ? you mean "file scope" I guess... there is no such "static scope" in C.